# Stripe Checkout: Is it possible to create a subscription that does not automatically renew?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, stripe-payments

I have an app that is built with React and Firebase, along with the [Run Payments with Stripe](https://extensions.dev/extensions/stripe/firestore-stripe-payments) Firebase extension. In the app, I sell a 24-hour usage license for a service (using [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout)).

This product is currently set up as a "one time" charge in Stripe. This isn't ideal for a few reasons:

- The activation status and period end aren't included in the Firestore Doc that Stripe creates in the `payments` collection (by contrast, when a subscription is purchased, Stripe automatically includes activation information in the Doc created in the `subscriptions` collection).
- Without additional code and Firestore updates/reads, a user can't prematurely cancel their activation period if they want to. It's also a hassle to enable users to extend their current activation period.

I would rather set up this product as a "recurring", daily billing cycle... except, I don't want the billing to actually recur.

In Stripe, is it possible to set up a subscription product that doesn't automatically renew? (Either as a setting within the Stripe dashboard, or as a property passed when creating a checkout session)

Comment: maybe what you want is to pause the subscription? Seems you can do this via the API: https://support.stripe.com/questions/how-to-pause-or-cancel-subscriptions?locale=en-GB

Comment: @AbdushSamadMiah I don't know if pause is what I'm looking for, but the link you shared also references canceling subscriptions (which is the answer I'm accepting, Nolan H just got there a minute quicker). Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this is not currently possible directly via Checkout settings, you can achieve this using webhooks.

By listening to either `checkout.session.completed` or `customer.subscription.created` events, your application could then set each newly created subscription to [cancel at the end of the first billing period](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/cancel?dashboard-or-api=api#cancel-at-end-of-cycle) (for you, the first day) using `cancel_at_period_end=true`.

For customers who do choose to renew, you can clear this settings to `false` before the end of the period to [allow the subscription to renew](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/cancel?dashboard-or-api=api#reactivating-canceled-subscriptions).

Comment: Unfortunately not quite the answer I was hoping for, but I think this is probably the best way to handle my case today. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the [subscription schedules](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules) API.
If I understand correctly your requirement, you could set up one unique *phase* of 24h after which the subscription would then be `released` or `canceled`, (`[end_behavior][2]` attribute from the schedules API)

I haven't looked at the Firebase Stripe extension in a while, so I can't tell whether you will tell be able to implement this with the extension.

Hope this helps.